# PHP mail - Spam Problems

Tags: php, email

I am trying to generate an email on signing up to website, I am using PHP to create and send the email. My domain has both SPF and DKIM running on it. However when i spam check my email i get this:

1. [SPF] srv61.hosting24.com does not allow your server 31.220.105.111 to use face159@srv61.hosting24.com
2. [Sender ID] srv61.hosting24.com does not allow your server 31.220.105.111 to use face159@srv61.hosting24.com
3. Your message is not signed with DKIM

I have contacted my hosting and they confirm that all the authentication systems are working on there end, so i must be doing something wrong in the PHP code but for the life of me i can't find what here is how i generate the email:

```
//Emails link to voucher    

//create a boundary for the email. This 
$boundary = uniqid('np');
$subject = "The Forum - Little Thank You";              
//headers - specify your from email address and name here
//and specify the boundary for the email

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From: TheForum@freewifisystems.co.uk" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "To: " . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";

//here is the content body
$message = "This is a MIME encoded message.";
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

//Plain Email
$content2 = "plain text email here";

//Plain text body
$message .= "Hello,\nThis is a text email as HMTL is dissable, Please enable    HTML to continue. \n\nRegards,\nThe Forum";
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

//Html body
$message .= $content3;
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";

//invoke the PHP mail function
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);


?>
```

$email and $content3 are set via SQL and are setting correctly the email forms and is well formatted.

Comment: There is a missing quote on the fourth line of the header - should probably be `$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";`

Comment: Hi yeah caught that just a copy error the actual code reads:$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";